# How to find code that is missing type annotations?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a project that is fully annotated. Or at least I hope so, because it is entirely possible that there is a function or two somewhere in there that is missing type annotations. How can I find such functions (or any other blocks of code)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use mypy for this. Just add some switches  to the command call:

```
$ mypy --disallow-untyped-calls --disallow-untyped-defs --disallow-incomplete-defs projectname
```

This will find you all untyped defines plus incomplete defines and also warns you if you call a untyped function.

For further information have a look at the [untyped-definitions-and-calls section of the mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#untyped-definitions-and-calls).